# Cannot configure SVN on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, svn, qt-creator, visualsvn-server

I have installed VisualSVN server and Win32Svn. Now I want to integrate it with Qt... I setup svn configuration in Tool -> Version control -> Subversion (see picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY3XG.png)

Now I want to create new project and add it to version control, but no option here :( (see picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKJNK.png)

I have absolutely no idea why... Can someone help me? What I did wrong or what I didn't?

Comment: and when the project is already created?

Comment: in the tools subversion menu isn't there an option to add a project to a repo?

Comment: no .. i can see anything like that

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If the repository already exists, try to use *Import project* -> *Subversion checkout* instead of *New project*.

Comment: I have created repository, but there is no qt project, because I cannon add project to repository ... when I use Import project -> Subversion checkout I will get empty repository